# Link shared through Facebook PHP SDK displays small thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I have written some code that automatically uploads an image to my site and then uses the PHP SDK to share the link of the page on which it is subsequently displayed.

This works, but the issue I am having is that it is displayed on Facebook in the format you can see here: http://boredatuni.com/images/fbshare1.png

Whereas other sites that share links on my wall appear like so: http://boredatuni.com/images/fbshare2.png

I am assuming this is an issue with my implementation of the PHP SDK, but I can't for the life of me work out how.  The code I am using to post to Facebook is as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'message' => $title,
    'link' => $link,
    'access_token' => $fanpageToken
);
$result = $this->facebook->api( '/' . $fanpageId . '/links', 'post', $args );
```

The correct image is being used on Facebook as I am using the Open Graph meta tag (og:image), but it is being displayed too small despite the fact I am using a script to ensure the image is returned at a defined width of 400x209.

Does anybody know how I can change the format to use the larger sized image?

Comment: I am facing the same problem, How did you fixed? Please can your share some knowledge regarding this?

Comment: I did not fix it unfortunately.  I believe, like Charles V says below, that only "approved" developers or pages with a certain number of Likes get this improved display.  Could well be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have been conducting some tests :

- post a link directly from Facebook
- post the exact same link though API

There was a different result whereas Facebook should parse exactly the same info (so an url to an appropriate og:image tag).

I believe that Facebook has disabled on purpose the display of big images in case of API called posts to limit visibility of post generated from Apps for "unapproved" developers. Because sharing link within Hootsuite works (i.e. displays a big image).